# Rails - How to create a model linked to TWO of another model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I  am trying to create the following:

```
User model (this is fine)

id

Link model (associated with two Users)

id
user_id1
user_id2
```

Is this an instance in which I would want to use the has_and_belongs_to_many association type on the Link model? How should I do this?

Ultimately, I would like to be able to have a user object and call @user.links to get all links involving that user...

I'm just not sure what the best way to do this in Rails is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will very likely want two models structured as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships #...
end

class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'friend_id'
end 

# ...and hence something like this in your view
<% for friendship in @user.friendships %>
  <%= friendship.status %>
  <%= friendship.friend.firstname %>
<% end %>
```

(This pattern is from a post made by [Ryan Bates](http://railscasts.com/) about two years ago during [this discussion](http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=1707) on [RailsForum](http://railsforum.com/).)

---

Just a note: this is now quite old. You may want to consider evaluating other strategies for handling this in a modern Rails context.

Answer (score 1):

You can create A Join Model that relation between the Link between the two users models

so basically

```
class User

  has_many :links, :through => :relationships

end

class Relationship

  belongs_to :user_id_1, :class=> "User"
  belongs_to :user_id_2, :class=> "User"

end
```